# React Native cannot find entry file in any of the roots

Tags: react-native

#### Description

Cloned a repo to a new computer and getting the following error:

```
swipes@0.0.1 start C:\a\swipes-api\mobile
node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Scanning 722 folders for symlinks in C:\a\swipes-api\mobile\node_modules (30ms)
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│  Running packager on port 8081.                                            │
│                                                                            │
│  Keep this packager running while developing on any JS projects. Feel      │
│  free to close this tab and run your own packager instance if you          │
│  prefer.                                                                   │
│                                                                            │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                  │
│                                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Looking for JS files in
  C:\a\swipes-api\mobile

error: bundling: NotFoundError: Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["C:\\a\\swipes-api\\mobile"]
    at DependencyGraph._getAbsolutePath (C:/a/swipes-api/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:280:11)
    at DependencyGraph.getDependencies (C:/a/swipes-api/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:218:26)
    at Resolver.getDependencies (C:/a/swipes-api/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/Resolver/index.js:107:27)
    at C:/a/swipes-api/mobile/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/Bundler/index.js:591:37
    at next (native)
    at step (C:\a\swipes-api\mobile\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Bundler\index.js:12:445)
    at C:\a\swipes-api\mobile\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Bundler\index.js:12:605
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
Bundling `index.android.js`  0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

The path is correct where it's searching from. I've been stuck with this for the whole day now.

Is this somehow because there are double backslashes in the path to the index file?

npm start -- --reset-cache results in the same error.
Running yarn start after react-native run-android results in the same issue as well.
npm run start -- --root C:\a\swipes-api\mobile  - No result.

This does not seem to be connected to the previous issue in the RN 0.45.0.

#### Additional Information

- React Native version: 0.45.1
- Platform: Android
- Development Operating System: Windows

### Edit:

All new projects with react-native init result in the same issue. Seems to be an issue with the config of my computer or npm, but I can't seem to track down why this happens.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope, but I did get closer with finding the root of the problem. Going in more depth here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14736

Comment: Did you use `watchman watch-del-all`?

Comment: Also related: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14246

Answer (score 0):

I have this and some like this error on windows.

Updating the `npm` and the `node` helped me on this issue.

currently i have:

```
C:\usr\Far>node -v && npm -v
v6.11.1
3.10.10
```

Many trials to run was not successful at all until I do not update. Anyway some errors like this appear time to time. Just restart. Also helpful to do before restart (but may be not need, just restart):

```
sh -c 'rm -rf $TMP/react*'
npm cache clean
```

Where `$TMP` is your system tmp directory, (check for existence react temp files there)

If you add or update some packages or some like that modifications concerning `node_modules` directory need to do also:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```